# FuelPHP: Add multiple many-to-many relationships

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I have two MySQL tables, subjects and books, and a third table to define many-to-many relationships between these two:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isbn13` char(13) NOT NULL,
  `isbn10` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `edition` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books_subjects` (
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`subject_id`,`book_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subjects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `institution_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

To add a new subject, I use the ORM package:

```
<?php    
$subject = Model_Subject::forge(array(
    'name' => Input::post('name'),
    'institution_id' => Input::post('institution_id'),
));

$subject->save();
?>
```

I have also added the many-to-many relationship to the Subject model:

```
protected static $_many_many = array('books');
```

Retrieving subjects with their assigned books works fine (I have added a few records to the books_subjects table manually), but I don't know how to add the relationships using the ORM package.
The relationships are in an array like this (retrieved by using Input::post()):

```
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
```

For someone with some experience with FuelPHP this should be pretty easy, but I just cant seem to figure it out...

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://docs.fuelphp.com/packages/orm/relations/many_many.html)? Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried multiple things, couldn't get it to work. Also, the documentation doesn't explain how to add multiple relationships (books to the subject in this case)

Comment: For example, I tried adding this line to the forge parameter array: `'books' => new Model_Book(Input::post('books')),` and this one: `'books' => Input::post('books'),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<?php    
$subject = Model_Subject::forge(array(
    'name' => Input::post('name'),
    'institution_id' => Input::post('institution_id'),
));

$subject->save();

foreach (Input::post('books') as $book_id) {
    $subject->books[] = Model_Book::find($book_id);
}

$subject->save();
?>
```

Comment: Apart from the first $subject->save() being unnecessary, it worked perfectly, thanks!